# The program does'nt give output

Tags: c++

I am using the following code to print out the code, and i doesn't show the correct area of the circle. it shows -215487854145 as the area of the circle..

please help me
the code below code:

kindly help me as i am new to this language, i think i did everything right please

```
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     int a, r;
     a = 3.14 * r * r ;

     cout << "enter Radius";

     cin >> r;

     cout << "area of circle is";
     cout << a;

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reading uninitialized variables resulting in undefined behavior. As an aside: you should always verify that reading a value was successful before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `r` in a calculation before you ever read in the value. Move it *after* you read it in.

```
cin >> r;
a = 3.14 * r * r ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Two issues.

1. You are computing `a` using an *unitialised* value of `r`. The program behaviour is *undefined*. Move it after the `cin >> r;` statement.
2. Working in `int` could cause you issues with overflow. The largest possible value of an `int` in C++ can be as small as 32767. Use a `double` instead, and an improved value of PI. Note that the *type* of `3.14 * r * r` is a `double` anyway, and you're currently forcing a conversion to `int`.

As for PI itself, it is not included in the C++ standard library. Consider

`constexpr double pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338328;`

or take one from a mathematics library if you're using one.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in mathematics,

```
a = 3.14 * r * r ;
```

does not define a relationship between `a` and `r` (it's not an equation).
Instead, it means "replace the current value of `a` with 3.14 times the square of the current value of `r`".
Since you haven't given `r` a value yet, the result is undefined.

You need to move the lines around a bit in order to not use values that don't exist yet.
You should also not use integers for this, but floating-point.

```
 double r;
 cout << "enter Radius";
 cin >> r;
 double a = 3.14 * r * r ;
 cout << "area of circle is " << a;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a, r;
  // your r was not initialized when you use it.
  a = 3.14 * r * r ;

  cout << "enter Radius";

  cin >> r;

  cout << "area of circle is";
  cout << a;

  return 0;
}
```

right answer:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
 {
    int a, r;

    cout << "enter Radius";

    cin >> r;

    //after r being initialized.
    a = 3.14 * r * r;
    cout << "area of circle is";
    cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```